# input datetime local delete style ios css

Tags: html, css, safari, ios16

Please tell me, with the release of the new version of ios 16 in safari, input time, input datetime are displayed incorrectly. How can I fix it?

`-webkit-appearance: none;` does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was just unprefixed, if you try without `-webkit-`, it should work. Although, for backup compatibility for the devices not updated or not supporting latest iOS, it would be good to maintain prefixed version as well.